# Android verify apk signature

Tags: android, apk

How to verify that some downloaded apk file is genuine. I.e. not modified and signed by trusted entity - by trusted entity I mean e.g. the same entity that signed the application that is performing the check?

I want to perform the check programatically from an Android app using java code.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the [PackageInfo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo) for the downloaded apk, there is some data about [signing](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/SigningInfo) in there

```
final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
String apk = "downloaded.apk";
String fullPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + apk;        
PackageInfo packageInfo = pm.getPackageArchiveInfo(fullPath, 0);
```